# VBA Excel avoiding for loops with variable column

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I’m using VBA for the first time. Up till now, I succeeded in building a model. However, I would still like to speed up calculations (I have already turned off ScreenUpdating, EnableEvents, xlCalculationAutomatic, DisplayPageBreaks). I have read on the internet that for-loops are quite time-consuming. Unfortunately, I really have a lot of them. Therefore, my question:

Assume I have this type of code:

```
 For p = 1 To Periods
 Demand(p) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 1 + p)
 Next p
```

My first question: Does this for-loop really slow down run time?
Second question: How can I rewrite it, thereby speeding up calculations?

I have been trying the following:

```
 Demand = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 2), Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 1 + Periods))
```

But unfortunately, this does not seem to work. I have already Googled this, but I do not seem to find an answer.

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It's not the `For` loops that take the time, it's what you do inside them. With Excel VBA, one of the slowest things you can do is interact with worksheets.

One quick change you could consider is this:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For p = 1 To Periods
        Demand(p) = .Cells(3, 1 + p)
    Next p
End With
```

... which means that your code knows it's always dealing the the same worksheet and doesn't have to look up the right one each time you go around the loop. You're probably not going to notice much difference, but you've gone from one worksheet lookup per period to one per run. You still have a cell lookup per period, though.

You *can* get to a single call to the worksheet though: get all the values in one call and avoid the loop completely:

```
Demand = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 2).Resize(1, Periods).Value
```

That's going to get you a 1 x Periods array in `Demand`. Try it - use "View...Locals Window" to see what you've got.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. The quick change was already a huge improvement. However, I have some problems to try the single call. I get this error: "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch". Do you have any idea where it could have gone wrong?

Comment: Are you declaring `Demand`? Something like `Dim Demand(1 To Periods)`? If so, try removing the type declaration, `Dim Demand` or explicitly making it a `Variant`: `Dim Demand As Variant`. Otherwise, as already noted, we need to see more code, especially what happens leading up to the problem line...

Comment: Thanks again. I did declare Demand. Now everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It actually *depends* how large your end counter is and how small your steps are. You'll likely to experience noticeable slowdowns if your end counter is > 500K (Really big).

However, you should consider the following:

**Optimizing the instructions inside the loop**

Your speed is more likely to be influenced by the instructions inside the loop. You're better off optimizing them then worrying whether you should use a `For each` or a `For Loop`.

Exemple: Using `.Rows().EntireRow` property within a loop will often decrease the speed of your code because Excel would consider a row a range that accounts for a possibly one two million cells. That's exactly what's going to slow your code done.

**Avoid using repetitive referencing**

`With` Statements are  a good way to increase the speed of your code. Just make sure that your loops are nested within a `With` statement. That way, VBA would not have to go through parents references multiple times.

@Mike Woodhouse's answer is a good example of how you can use a `With` statement to increase the speed of your code.

VBA will execute Periods time your instructions with one reference to the `Worksheets("Sheet1")`:

```
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For p = 1 To Periods
        Demand(p) = .Cells(3, 1 + p)
    Next p
End With
```

However in your old code (below), VBA execute your instruction and in doing that, it will call Periods time `WorkSheets("Sheet1")`

```
For p = 1 To Periods
 Demand(p) = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(3, 1 + p)
 Next p
```